# Use DBCC with select

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get the MessageText field from DBCC output, but this returns syntax error

```
SELECT MessageText FROM (DBCC CHECKDB (test) WITH TABLERESULTS)
```

What should I use?

In SMSS it can detect and return the MessageText field only, how did microsoft do it?

Comment: It seems the duplicate fails to address your problem. Am I right to think that you want to get this result in a programmatic way and not with creating a temporary table?

Comment: @Steve Indeed, I believe SMSS is not creating a table to do that, and it works without "WITH TABLERESULTS"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get back, directly in your program, the results of a DBCC command you need to subscribe to the [InfoMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) event of the SqlConnection class.

```
void Main()
{
    string db = "Linqpadtest";
    List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cnn.InfoMessage += (s, e) =>
        {
            messages.Add(e.Message);
        };
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"DBCC CHECKDB ('{db}')", cnn);
        _ = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, messages);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**When you specify `WITH TABLERESULTS`, the results come back as a table. However, it is difficult to access it via SQL, as it is similar to getting results from a stored procedure.**

You could use `INSERT...EXEC...`, perhaps, but in C#, you can just use standard ADO reading mechanisms to get a specific column.

The easiest way to do this is with a `DataReader`:

```cs
using(var cnn = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("DBCC CHECKDB (test) WITH TABLERESULTS", cnn) {CommandTimeout = 3600});
{
    cnn.Open();
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            Console.WriteLine(reader["MessageText"]);
    }
}
```

I have added `CommandTimeout = 3600` because `CHECKDB` can take a long time.